# How to refresh a page onclicking on one button in specific condition in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have two options in my Navbar. *Shop* and *MyCart* . From shop section i can add products in mycart, so when i am in shop section and click on Mycart from navbar then a minicart slide will toggle from right side, but when i am in mycart page from navbar, then if i click the cart icon then the page should refresh, in my case it's appearing the toggle right side button, which is wrong, i have to refresh the total page when i am in mycart section.

`TopNavBar.vue`

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="link" href="/shop">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li class="userIcons" @click="showmyCart">
      <span class=" link">MYCart <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import MyMiniCart from "./MyMiniCart";

export default {
  name: "TopNavBar",
  data() {
    return {
      
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showmyCart(){
      var pageurl = window.location.pathname;
      if (pageurl == '/pathname') {
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        //another code snippet
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should not use `a` tags into a VueJS app (what version you're using btw, 2 or 3?) but rather `router-link` ([vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/)) to preserve the current state. Also, it's not fully clear as of what is happening here. Can you use some Vue devtools to check what is the state you do currently have (or missing)?

Comment: There are ways to "refresh" the Vue router, but you probably don't even need that here.

Comment: Thanks @kissu for your reply, i tried with your approach, can you please give me an idea how to refresh one page in vue.js?

Comment: You don't need such thing as a "refresh" in an SPA. What do you want to do exactly (regarding the behavior/state)?

Comment: @kissu i want to refresh the page, i tried with this.$router.push(), reload() also, but nothing works.

Comment: `window.location.reload()` then.

Comment: Hi @kissu its worked, can you post it as a separate answer? then i'll make it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to hard refresh the page, you can use the following.

```js
window.location.reload()
```

---

Meanwhile, I recommend that you use [`$router.push`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) or keep your state reactive.

Comment: Yes i tried $router.push , but i got one error ->  "$router is not defined"
and if i use this.$router.push , then i got -> "push is not defined"
Can you please rectify this error?

Comment: @user18286913 please provide more context by editing your question. `this.$router.push` should be totally available in a `script` tag.

Comment: If i use `this.$router.push` then i am getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')` error in console

Comment: @user18286913 context is important here. **Where** do you use it? Please update your question with a relevant piece of code snippet.

Comment: I have updated the code, please have a look.

Comment: @user18286913 did you set vue-router? https://router.vuejs.org/ You can create a test project with the CLI to see what configuration needs to be made there. Not sure if you're using Vue2 or 3 here tho but here you go: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application